# A better way to create multiple objects in one go in Django

Tags: django

How can I improve this block of code?

Should I put everything in the save method? Use multiple try..except blocks? Also, how can I roll back the entire transaction such that if it fails at one of the 'create' stages, the rest of the previously created objects gets rolled back.

```
@login_required
def admin_import_residents_confirm(request, comp_slug, file_id):
    comp = get_object_or_404(Comp, slug=comp_slug)
    file = get_object_or_404(ResidentImportFile, id=file_id)
    resident_list = ResidentImportData.objects.filter(comp=comp, 
            file=file)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        for resident in resident_list:
            try:
                # create the user objects here
                pw = User.objects.make_random_password(length=6, 
                        allowed_chars='1234567890')
                fusername = '{0}{1}{2}'.format(resident.first_name, 
                            resident.last_name, 
                            re.sub('\D', '', resident.unit_number))
                user = User.objects.create(
                        username = fusername, 
                        password = pw, 
                        first_name = resident.first_name, 
                        last_name = resident.last_name)

                # second create the profile objects
                Profile.objects.create(user=user,
                        contact_number=resident.contact_number)

                # third create the role objects
                role = Role.objects.filter(comp=comp,
                        name=2)[0]
                role.user.add(user)

                # fourth create the usercomp object
                Usercomp.objects.create(
                        user=user,
                        comp=comp,
                        unit_number=resident.unit_number,
                        block_number=resident.block_number)

                # fifth store the one time passwords
                TempPasswords.objects.create(
                        user=user,
                        password=pw)

                # sixth update created status
                resident.is_created = True
                resident.save()

            except Exception, e:
                print e
                url = reverse('admin_import_residents_confirm', 
                        args=[comp.slug, file.id ])
                return redirect(url)

        url = reverse('admin_resident_list', args=[comp.slug])
        return redirect(url)
```

Comment: You will get an exception on third line.

Comment: What problems have you got with the code? Why one would step fail? Has it failed before?

Answer (score 0):

You use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) to create all the other objects once the initial user has been created. This way you can break the chunks up into separate methods/signal receievers (one for the profile, one for the temp password etc.) all of which will be called when the initial user is created.

With regards a transaction - you can hold off committing the new objects to the DB until after they have all been created, meaning that if you get out of the try/catch without an exception you know all the objects are created and therefore save them. This becomes more difficult if you break the single method into smaller signal receivers.